# CRA: `react-scripts` Update from 3 -> 4 Breaks Inline CSS Style Usage

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-scripts, inline-styles

I have upgraded the `react-scripts` package with my TS React App from `3.4.0` to latest `4.0.3` to fix a package security error.

But for some reason this has had the effect of all Inline CSS styles within the app not being generated for some reason.

For example, an element that was previously rendering as:

```html
<span class="ant-typography text-body-s release-meta-date" style="color: rgb(140, 140, 140);">Example Element Text</span>
```

is now just rendering as:

```html
<span class="ant-typography text-body-s release-meta-date">Example Element Text</span>
```

So is just defaulting to default style rules

I've been trying to find an answer on endless GitHub issue pages, blog posts, docs, and have tried many different setups to get it working, to no success.

Have tried upgrading TS and React packages and types all to latest versions along with `react-scripts`

Anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

My current `package.json` changes and potentially relevant packages:

```json
  "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
  "craco-less": "^1.17.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
  "react": "16.14.0",
  "react-dom": "16.14.0"
```

Something that I think may be playing a factor is the fact that I have some package `"resolutions"` setup (as whole team is using `yarn`) that were needed to fix previous issues:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
  "webpack": "4.44.2",
  "d3-color": "3.0.1"
}
```

Could it be an issue with the `craco.config`, or `less-loader`, or `babel-loader`, or `webpack` specific setup / config?

Fully lost here now, any help would be great!